# How do I keep values in 2 different sheets in sync?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has some dates on it, like "25/02/2016", listed down a column. On the cells to the right of each date, there are some numeric values.

I need to copy these numeric values to a specific range on a different sheet. Ideally, it would work like a one-way sync, where I would write values on sheet1 and sheet2 would automatically be updated.

I've been looking through the Google Apps Script documentation, but I have no idea where to start. I do have some pseudo-code, just don't how to use it here.

```
function getDates() {
    for (count = 0; count < sheet1.length; count++) {
        if (hasDate) {
            return(cell);
        }
    }
}
var numericValuesRows = sheet1.getDates().getRow();
var numericValuesRange = numericValuesRows.selectColumns(C-F);
```

Just making up method names and syntax. This bit is supposed to find out which rows have dates in them, and then select columns C to F in those rows. The next one is supposed to select the destination as all the cells from row3:columnC to row10:columnF, and copy the previously selected values to there.

```
var outputRange = sheet2.cellRange(C3-F10);
numericValuesRange.copyTo(outputRange);
```

I realise it's really crappy pseudo-code, but I'm hoping it at least helps in some way get across what I want to do. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you want to use code instead of a formula, you'll probably need to trigger the code to run with a simple `onEdit()` function.  So, whenever there is an edit, the code runs.  However, if any of the values in sheet 1 are changed with code, this won't work.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason why not or this is a small part of a bigger script, the IMPORTRANGE() formula combined with other logic is likely to be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onEdit()` trigger which will trigger when you edit a sheet. You can check the source of the edit to make sure its an edit to the cells you want in a particular sheet. Once that's done, its a matter of using `getValue()`, `setValue()` and `getSheetByName()`. Start here: [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)